# generate custom output link

Tags: javascript, node.js

I am trying to make an app which should do the following:

- step 1) user enters input into a textarea
- step 2) that input is posted to the server
- step 3) server is processing that input and generating an ouput
- step 4) server generates a custom url (.../output/output_ID) where the output is shown and immediately redirects the user to that url

the issue is with step 4). I am using raw javascript for front-end and nodejs with express for backend.

**client side:**

```
fetch('/postInput', {
                method : 'POST',
                body : JSON.stringify({input : inputBox.value.toString()}),
                headers: new Headers({ "Content-Type": "application/json" })
            })
```

**server side:**

```
app.post('/postInput/', jsonParser, (req, res) => {
    let inputText = req.body;
    let output = processInput(inputText);
    let outputID = generateOutputId();
    // now the user should be redirected to the following link:
    // /output/outputID
    // the new url should show the output
});
```

Answer (score 0):

There are two possible solutions, depending on your "architecture":

- If you are posting the data using a good old submit button, then you could send a response with the `302` status and a `Location` header that contains the required URL
- If you are posting the data using Javascript with an `XMLHttpRequest`, then you'll have to redirect with this Javascript line: `location = 'your URL'`